# Drupal 7 Get field value by machine name and pass to javascript

Tags: nodes, entities, javascript, hooks

I have tried to do this a couple of different ways, but I will just include the latest.

My task is to build a module that will get the STRING value of a taxonomy term by the machine name of the field when the page is rendered, and pass that STRING value to a javascript function to output data in a block.

Most recently, I have tried adding the code to the template.php file in the preprocess_html, page, node and process_html:

*The field is called 'field_test'

```
global $nid;
$node = node_load('12');
$test = $node->field_test['und'][0]['value'];
drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('test' => $test)), 'setting');
```

Error in processes was a call to undefined index.
Error in page.tpl was a call to non object.

I also tried field_get_items:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_test');
$first_item = array_shift($items);
$test = $first_item['value'];
```

In the node.tpl file, I tried adding this code:

```
<?php
  $test = $node->field_test['und'][0]['value'];
  drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('test' => $test)), 'setting');
?>
```

No errors, but Drupal.settings.test returns undefined in the browser console.

I'll admit I am still new to the Drupal API. In addition to the **correct code,** I may also lack an understanding of the order in which Drupal components are loaded, and specifically **where the code should be placed**.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Could you include the Drupal version you are using in the question?

Comment: It should be `Drupal.settings.mymodule.test` not `Drupal.settings.test`. All of this code should live in a preprocess hook (either page or node, whichever is more appropriate for your use case). For the node, you can try `$node = menu_get_object('node');`.

Comment: Updating to include Drupal version - thanks @neograph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Drupal.settings.mymodule.test` not `Drupal.settings.test`. All of this code should live in a preprocess hook (either page or node, whichever is more appropriate for your use case). For the node, you can try `$node = menu_get_object('node');`.

Example:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object('node')) {
  $tid = $node->field_test['und'][0]['tid'];
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('test' => $term->name)), 'setting');
}
```

In your console (like Google Chrome) you can type `Drupal.settings` to see the entire object, and you should see `mymodule` as a part of it. Within that you will find test with the term name as a value.

Comment: Killer. That did it. You rock!