# Get field value by machine name

Tags: theming, entities, javascript

I developed a custom module in Drupal 7. I asked a similar question here: 
[Drupal 7 Get field value by machine name and pass to javascript](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247431/drupal-7-get-field-value-by-machine-name-and-pass-to-javascript)

But the difference in this question is, instead of a taxonomy term, I want to get the field value of a regular text field.

Here is the code that I use to get the field value of a taxonomy term to pass to javascript, which currently resides in my theme's hook_process_page function:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object('node')) {
  $tid = $node->field_test['und'][0]['tid'];
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('test' => $term->name)), 'setting');
}
```

Some things that I can see might ned to be changed right away are "tid," "taxonomy_term_load."

How can I change this code to instead get the text value of a field instead of a taxonomy term, to pass to mymodule?

EDIT:

Per a suggested change, I've modified the code, though I'm not sure this is what was meant:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object('node')) {
  $fieldValue = $node->field_test['und'][0]['value'];
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($fieldValue);
  drupal_add_js(array('jsblock' => array('test' => $fieldValue->name)), 'setting');
}
```

The in response to Drupal.settings.jsblock.test, the console outputs null.

Here is the Drupal notice:

[image: property of non-object]

Devel results:

[image]

How can I get the field value and pass it to my jsblock module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion you wrote for your code

```
$fieldValue = $node->field_test['und'][0]['value'];  
$term = taxonomy_term_load($fieldValue);
```

If you require only value then your purpose gets solved at this line of code

```
$fieldValue = $node->field_test['und'][0]['value'];
```

Secondly the function taxonomy_term_load() expects tid as parameter and you are sending a value string, hence it will throw an error. See the API document. 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7.x

You should just send the variable to javascript file as this

```
drupal_add_js(array('jsblock' => array('test' => $fieldValue)), 'setting');
```

Answer (score 0):

For text fields you can use

```
$value = $node->field_my_field_name['und'][0]['value'];
```

or, if you want sanitized value, use `['safe_value']`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I updated my code in post post after "EDIT:" I'm still getting some errors. I'm not sure if I did what you meant. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: in your modified/repurposed code, you no longer need `$term = taxonomy_term_load($fieldValue);`, and the error is a result of calling the "name" value of your variable, rather than the variable itself `array('test' => $fieldValue)`

Comment: Thank you to you also @Anson for clarifying the drupal_add_js function!

Comment: **Note:** Using `['und']` will not work if you enable translation for that field. See **[Best practice for language key for “und” in hook_form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/best-practice-for-language-key-for-und-in-hook-form-alter)**